# mysql joining two tables vs using in condition

Tags: mysql

mysql - i have two tables as below

**table1**

```
city code, city name
1, chicago
2, miami
3, NY
```

**table2**

```
branch,branch name, city code, day, amt
50,a,1,jan, $10
32,b,2,feb, $30
```

i want to find branch and branch name where total amt in Jan was >$50 for brances in NY

i have code as below

```
select branch, branch name, sum(amt) from table2
where city code = (select city code from table1 where  city name = 'NY')
and day="jan"
group by branch, branch name
having sum(amt)>50
```

1. is the above code correct?
2. if i want cities `NY` and `chicago` then can i modify where clause as

`where city code in (select city code from table1 where  city name in ('NY','chicago')`

3. how could achieve same results by joining the both tables (single query)?
4. what is the most efficient way to get this output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query #2 is correct.

The equivalent with a join is:

```
select table2.branch, table2.branch name, sum(table2.amt) 
from table2
join table1 on table1.citycode = table2.citycode
where table2.day="jan"
and table1.cityname in ('NY', 'Chicago')
group by branch, branch name
having sum(amt)>50
```

In my experience, MySQL performs much better with the join than `where in (subquery)`.